# Should we require users to check ChatGPT before posting their question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, chatgpt

With the release of ChatGPT, a large majority of simple coding questions can be answered by ChatGPT.

Should we thus require that users check ChatGPT before posting their question, to avoid trivial questions that can be effectively answered by AI? This would also help justify the ban on ChatGPT: if only questions that ChatGPT **cannot** answer are acceptable, it follows that ChatGPT answers should be banned.

Comment: What make you think that "a large majority of simple coding questions can be answered by ChatGPT."?

Comment: @Rubén personal experience using it for my own work to answer simple questions that I'd normally go to Stackoverflow for

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I voted because I thought it was necessarily opinion based until someone conducts a formal study and it gets published in peer-reviewed literary, the usual...

Comment: How are the users supposed to know an answer by ChatGPT 1. works and 2. is good? A large portion of the users who ask questions *do not know the answer*. And that's a prerequisite to examining a ChatGPT answer. And I have seen accepted ChatGPT answers where the question author came back later and commented "this doesn't work". Which sounds paradoxical but it's typical of users to accept an answer before checking it.

Comment: @bad_coder a formal, peer-reviewed study would be nice but a more informal analysis is ok too. 100 samples, 3 humans, 10 domains, 1h, done, that would already be an interesting start.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that would be something and I'm sure the community would be interested in reading it, but as these things are also a kind of *hype-of-the-moment* I'm in *wait-and-see* mode until a credible group of folks decides to take their time - because there is a distinct possibility no one will organize such a study in the near term. Anyway, I've cast a reopen vote and lets keep the Q around since it already gathered some answers.

Comment: Good luck using ChatGPT generated code. When it breaks in weird unknown ways, make yourself surprised.

Comment: @VLAZ how are users supposed to know if an answer on StackOverflow written by humans is working and good, especially for less popular questions?

Comment: @JonathanReez There is the whole "voting by other humans" part which is cut out by your proposition. Also, what you say now sounds like you have shifter the purpose of SO. It's supposed to be for *finding* question. Read much, write less kind of resource. If you expect users to take all their questions immediately to SO, then the model is already broken.

Comment: @VLAZ well most users don't ask their questions on SO because they find an existing SO answer in Google. And human voting would be present even for answers generated by ChatGPT and other AI systems.

Comment: The assumption in the first sentence of this question, upon which the entire question is based, is false. As has been explained in *many* places, both here on SO/SE and on non-SE sites, ChatGPT has *no concept* of "correct" or "accurate". The *only* thing it does is string words together in "eloquent bullshit". Because it is "eloquent bullshit", ChatGPT answers are *often* perceived as correct by many people when the answers are fundamentally flawed. This is particularly true for readers who are not experts in the particular thing being asked about and/or not reading critically.

Comment: @Makyen um... I'm not the world's best software engineer but I find it very useful for quick answers to simple questions that SO would normally solve for me. Just recently it was able to provide a great answer to "how do I debug why DNS doesn't work?" that I couldn't easily replicate via Google search. A non-expert might not necessarily know what the "best" answer is, but surely they could at least try the proposed solution and see if it works? I might be biased because I actually know what I'm doing, but I do see it as a great tool *today*.

Comment: @Makyen as a corollary, how do people know that *human* answers on SO are correct/accurate? For questions with <10 upvotes I routinely find the answer to be incorrect or misleading after I try it out myself.

Comment: ChatGPT does, on rare occasions, give correct answers. It's like a slot machine. People see (what they perceive as) correct answers every once in a while and *massively* overestimate the rate at which ChatGPT produces a correct answer. As mentioned above, that someone *perceives* an answer to be correct *often* doesn't reflect the reality of if the answer actually is correct/accurate. Those mis-categorizations as "correct" also substantially contribute to over-estimations as to ChatGPT's rate of correct/accurate answers.

Comment: @JonathanReez "*well most users don't ask their questions on SO because they find an existing SO answer in Google.*" I'm well aware they don't find an answer. Most of the time, that's because they don't try. "*And human voting would be present even for answers generated by ChatGPT and other AI systems.*" that's not what you suggested, though. You just said that users should be shooed away to ask ChatGPT. Which doesn't have any concept of right or wrong answers. It presents both equally. Nobody is rating them.

Comment: @JonathanReez "*as a corollary, how do people know that human answers on SO are correct/accurate*" we've been over this: voting.

Comment: @JonathanReez What you're asking in comments has been discussed multiple times. Please read the plethora of other discussions on MSE and MSO about ChatGPT. I don't really feel like taking the time to go through this *again*, just for you. That may sound callous, but you're asking us to do the work of organizing and answering these issues just for you (and we've already spent a *huge* amount of time on ChatGPT, and addressing those issues when bought up by others). If what you're asking about in comments here was asked as a question, we'd be closing it as a duplicate of other discussions.

Answer (score 13):

This raises several problems:

1. ChatGPT is only one service of such kind. There might be many more such services (of varying quality). Should we recommend one versus the other? Should we recommend all?
2. Currently, I don't see why users **have to** check ChatGPT for an answer. They can, but I don't see why it should be a Stack Exchange's job to require them to.
3. As of December 2022, the concept of meaningful (subjective proportion) answers on general questions auto-generated by ChatGPT-like service is quite new to begin **immediate** changes on the Q/A workflow.

**Therefore, no**, I don't see why Stack Exchange should require users to check ChatGPT (or any other service) before posting their questions.

Comment: *Should we recommend all?* => we should probably recommend the most advanced one that's on the list of banned services. Possibly different ones for different types of questions.

Comment: *is quite new to begin immediate changes on the Q/A workflow* => well, there's already been an immediate change in the form of a ban :-)

Comment: Additionally - the first answer on the [ChatGPT FAQ](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6783457-chatgpt-faq) is: "*During the initial research preview, ChatGPT is free to use.*" --- So ChatGPT is not a finished service. There is a high probability that a similar service will not be provided for free in the future.